# PHP/Git - Which files to include / link in my own file?

Tags: php, git, paypal

I have shared hosting to try and test my PHP projects. I'm still learning to code so excuse my silly questions. From various tutorials online I learnt that I don't need to install git to use code from GitHub. I learned that I can download the code from GitHub and host the files directly to my hosting.

Given that I'm not using Composer/Git to get the source due to restrictions on my host and PC (admin restrictions). How will I know which file to use to link to in my own files e.g. `require ('library/PayPal-PHP-SDK-master/filename.php');` say in my index.php

When I tried to use PayPal's SDK and I tried to run one of their sample codes I was given this error `The 'vendor' folder is missing. You must run 'composer update' to resolve application dependencies. Please see the README for more information.;`

Obviously, since I can't use composer, I can't resolve the above. How can I go around it, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to use composer, you can grab the SDK zip that contains Paypal PHP Rest API SDK with all its dependencies with it.

Instructions

Download latest/desired release zip file starting with PayPal-PHP-SDK-*.zip from Releases Section https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/releases

Go to your project directory. If you do not have one, just create a directory and cd in.

mkdir project
cd project
Unzip, and copy directory to your project location
This is how your directory structure would look like

[image]

then you could use the autoload.php with a require :)